# What does BeautifulSoup's multi_valued_attributes=None do?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, documentation

The documentation on ["multi_valued_attributes=None"](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#multi-valued-attributes) is rather unclear to me.

- Python 3.8.10
- BeautifulSoup 4.8.2-1 (python3-bs4)

Using the same string as source, the documentation seems to suggest that there should be two different results, depending upon the use of the `multi_valued_attributes` argument. However, I get identical results:

```
>>> rel_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Back to the <a rel="index">homepage</a></p>')
>>> rel_soup.a['rel']
['index']
>>> rel_soup.a['rel'] = ['index', 'contents']
>>> rel_soup.a['rel']
['index', 'contents']
>>> print(rel_soup.p)
<p>Back to the <a rel="index contents">homepage</a></p>
```

Adding in the multi_valued_attributes argument:

```
>>> rel_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Back to the <a rel="index">homepage</a></p>', "html", multi_valued_attributes=None)
>>> rel_soup.a['rel']
'index'
>>> rel_soup.a['rel'] = ['index', 'contents']
>>> rel_soup.a['rel']
['index', 'contents']
>>> print(rel_soup.p)
<p>Back to the <a rel="index contents">homepage</a></p>
```

Comment: Reading the documentation the attribute is used when you parse the html. So `<a rel="index sss">` the `a["rel"]` becomes `['index', 'sss']`. When `multi_valued_attributes=None` is specified `a["rel"]` becomes `index sss`

Comment: @AndrejKesely but, as shown above, it didn't behave that way. Both with, and without the argument, it printed as a list. Hence, my confusion. However, when I tried with a class instead of a rel, it behaved. (See answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

I see now that the documentation is not illustrating the difference well.

Using the second example without and with the `multi_valued_attribute` argument illustrates the difference much better. Using `class` rather than `rel`:

- **With**:

```
>>> no_list_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="body strikeout"></p>', 'html', multi_valued_attributes=None)
>>> no_list_soup.p['class']
'body strikeout'
```

- **Without**:

```
>>> no_list_soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="body strikeout"></p>')
>>> no_list_soup.p['class']
['body', 'strikeout']
```